python: "from library import module" works, but "import library.module" could not be resolved
I've got this dts:
Pipfile
module-common\
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  common\
    library-common.py
module-a\
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  functional-module\
    library-a.py
    library-b.py


Pipfile is defined as
...
[packages]
module-common = {file = "module-common", editable = true}
module-a = {file = "module-a", editable = true}


setup.py are defined as
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="module-common",
    version="2",
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)


and
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="module-a",
    version="2",
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)


init.py files are empty
I installed all with
pipenv install -e module-common
pipenv install -e module-a
pipenv install

pip list is correctly showing my packages into the dts
so, in library-a I want to use a function from library-common,
but this declaration of library-a fails
from common.library-common import SomeClass
print(f"function return: {SomeClass.function()}")

and results in:
NameError: name 'library-common' is not defined

but if I declare
import common
print(f"function return: {common.common-function.SomeClass.function()}")

I got the correct answer.
what am I missing here? how do I get first notation to work?
the purpose is trying not touch library-a code, leave the imports as they are to avoid refactoring the whole codebase
